# How can I append a constant to a variable in an Install4j text field?

Tags: variables, install4j

I am using the "Download File" action in Install4j, and I need to use a variable in the text field where you specify the URL from which to download the file. I know that I can use a variable like this: ${installer:codebase}. However, I need to append the file name onto the end of that variable. Does anyone know how to do that?

I have tried ${installer:codebase}filename.jpg and ${installer:codebase}+filename.jpg, but neither seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installer variables are simply replaced in text properties. For example, if you set it to

```
${installer:codebase}/filename.jpg
```

and the value of "codebase" is set to "http://mycorp.com", then the text after replacement will be

```
http://mycorp.com/filename.jpg
```